# python unable to use .whl files

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pymedia, but I can't. I know I need pip, but I can't get pip. on every tutorial, it always says to do

```
python -m ensurepip
```

but for me it always just says

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have windows 7 64 bit and python 2.7

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `python` is not on your `path`.

Check if the python directory with `python.exe` is listed in the environment variable `PATH`. If not, just add it and try again.

You should be able to start python shell by running `python` in command line.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 easy options. First you need to be running pip from your scrips folder in the python directory.

Download your `whl` file and place it in the scripts folder where your pip.exe is.

In command prompt (windows) type:

```
#note the exact file path may be different but should look something like this.
cd C:\program files\Python\Scripts
```

after you are in your scripts folder in command prompt you can then run the command:

```
pip install nameofpackage.whl
```

note if you have more than one python version installed make sure you are running pip in the correct directory and if you have `2.X` and `3.X` installed you may want to use `pip3` instead of `pip`

For windows users your second option here:

like the first option make sure you are in your scripts folder in command prompt then you can run a command to install your `whl` file on a local directory:

```
pip install C:/path/to/dir/with/filename.whl
```